# Passing map of functions to a macro

Tags: clojure

I have a macro that will implement a Java interface that is a listener. I defined the macro to take a map containing functions that I want to destructure, and use for each of the interfaces methods. This is the macro :-

```
(defmacro with-cache-listener-m [component event body]
   (let [{:keys [f-insert f-update]} body]
     `(. ~component addMapListener
     (proxy [AbstractMapListener] []
       (entryInserted [~event] ~f-insert ~event)
       (entryUpdated [~event] ~f-update ~event)))))
```

The body map is this :-

```
(def m-callbacks {:f-insert callback-insert :f-update callback-update})
```

But when I call `(macroexpand '(with-cache-listener-m test-cache e m-callbacks))` it expands to `(. test-cache user/addMapListener (clojure.core/proxy [com.tangosol.util.AbstractMapListener] [] (user/entryInserted [e] nil e) (user/entryUpdated [e] nil e)))`

The callback functions are nil. Do I need to define them differently or am I going about this the wrong way.

Comment: What are callback-insert and callback-update?  When you call m-callbacks what does it produce?

Comment: They are just two functions that print their argument and return. m-callbacks is 

user> m-callbacks
{:f-insert #<user$callback_insert user$callback_insert@1db87736>, :f-update #<user$callback_update user$callback_update@2d3584f9>}

Comment: What if you bind m-callbacks to a function that evaluates to this map instead of to the map directly?

Comment: (defn m-callbacks2 [] ({:f-insert callback-insert :f-update callback-update}))

Same result, both functions are nil in the macro expansion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call the `with-cache-listener-m` macro, the `body` argument get bounded to `'m-callbacks` as a symbol, so when you try to destructure that local var it won't work because it ain't a map. You can let the resulting form do the job like this:

```
(defmacro with-cache-listener-m [component event body]
  `(let [{:keys [f-insert# f-update#]} ~body]
     (. ~component addMapListener
        (proxy [AbstractMapListener] []
          (entryInserted [~event] f-insert# ~event)
          (entryUpdated [~event] f-update# ~event)))))
```

But in the end I'm not sure your code need a macro, have you tried to write it as a function:

```
(defn add-map-listener [component insert-fn update-fn]
  (.addMapListener component
    (proxy [AbstractMapListener] []
      (entryInserted [e] (insert-fn e))
      (entryUpdated [e] (update-fn e)))))
```

As you saw, I changed a couple of things:

- Made the function name clearer, your macro wasn't really like other with-* macros that usually evaluate some code (the `body`) in some kind of special context.
- Removed the event argument as it didn't seemed to have any use.
- Made the insert-fn and update-fn arguments explicit to simplify the example.
- Used the new method calling syntax.
- Fixed the proxy's methods to actually use the given functions.

If you want to make the functions completely optional and make it possible to be given in any order you could always do that:

```
(defn add-map-listener [component & functions]
  (let [{:keys [insert-fn update-fn]} (into {} functions)]
    (when-not (empty? functions)
      (.addMapListener component 
        (proxy [AbstractMapListener] []
          (entryInserted [e] (insert-fn e))
          (entryUpdated [e] (update-fn e)))))))
```

Notice that I've added code to not call addMapListener when no functions are given.

Comment: This is certainly a lot clearer, thank you. However, I still get the same error, as when I originally defined it as a function. My map of functions is (def m-callbacks {:insert-fn callback-insert :update-fn callback-update}), but when I call add-map-listener, I get an exception, No value supplied for key. m-callbacks evals to user> m-callbacks
{:insert-fn #<user$callback_insert user$callback_insert@1db87736>, :update-fn #<user$callback_update user$callback_update@2d3584f9>}

Comment: First, you'll need to use `apply` like this `(apply add-map-listener m-callbacks)` and second I've made a small mistake, the `functions` argument need to be transformed back into a map, it's fixed now.

Comment: You could also define `add-map-listener` with that args vector: `[component functions]` so that it directly take a map as argument. With the way I've defined it you could call it like that: `(add-map-listener test-cache :f-insert callback-insert :f-update callback-update)`

Comment: (apply add-map-listener test-cache m-callbacks) works. Thanks you, this was very educational. Not sure I understand the use of apply here, but will look that up now.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are not functions: they only know about the literal forms passed to them at compile-time. If you assign a value, say 10, to the var `x`, then pass `x` to your macro, it sees not 10 but `x`. Your macro will probably work fine if, instead of `def`ing `m-callbacks` and then passing that symbol, you simply pass the map directly as a literal.

Comment: I guess what I really want to know is how any Java listener interface that defines more than one method, can be implemented idiomatically in a macro. I tried this :-

user> (macroexpand '(with-cache-listener-m test-cache e '{:f-insert callback-insert :f-update callback-update}))


(. test-cache user/addMapListener (clojure.core/proxy [com.tangosol.util.AbstractMapListener] [] (user/entryInserted [e] nil e) (user/entryUpdated [e] nil e)))